# How do Wii U patches work?

Tags: wii-u

Do the Wii U patches effectively modify the data as it comes off the game disc? Or do they replace the main executable and run off internal storage?

Comment: While there's no way for us to know exactly how they work, we *can* figure out that they have to be stored on internal memory.  Discs are read-only, so there's no way to change the data on them.

Comment: My first thought (maybe a year ago) was that it just downloaded a whole new version of the game because the download was so big (and used up my monthly data allowance!) But then I thought why would you still need the disc to play the game? Hence my question about whether it loads some parts as they are and patches others during the load process.

Comment: The most efficient method would be to just download minimal patches; lowers the bandwidth usage, and a better user experience overall.  That said, I don't believe there's any way for us to actually be able to answer this; how Nintendo does it is the way they do it.